# fault handling state machine workflows

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I've built a state machine workflow with several states.

I have not incorporated any form of error control. I was reading about error control within state machine workflows and have come to the conclusion that there is no global form of error control but only per activity. Hence every activity will need its own form of error control. This would take me a lot of time to do and am wondering if its worth the effort. ?

What I think I require is to be informed if a workflow fails, the workflow has a status column, can this be used to email a admin of error ?

What are my choices on this ? Do developers always add error control in state machine workflows ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want information about failing workflows without doing any compensation for already occured actions then it's propbably easiest to implement a SPWorkflowEventReceiver listening for [SPWorkflowEventReceiver.WorkflowCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.workflowcompleted) and then check [SPWorkflowEventProperties.CompletionType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventproperties.completiontype).

This requires SP2010 and will not work if you want to do any real error handling.